# Why a wifi adapter would suddenly not support wireless N mode?

Tags: windows-10, 802.11n, wireless-adapter

I have my router set up to only allow n mode (802.11 N Support Required). This has worked to perfection for the last couple months. I started my laptop today and it refuses to connect to the Wifi, which has not happened before. After toying around I figured out that the adapter only wants to connect when wireless N support required is off. I tried updating drivers, netsh shows that it supports n mode, and no updates to the system have taken place. This is sudden and without any found cause. Are there any solutions for this? I have Windows 10 x64 Professional, and Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 Wifi adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your AP has QoS (WMM) enabled, and WPA2 (AES-CCMP) security if you use security at all. 802.11n technically requires both of those (WEP and original WPA/TKIP are not enough), and some client drivers will rightfully refuse to associate in 802.11n mode if those features aren't available. In that case, they'll usually still connect in a/b/g mode if it's available, but if it's not, they may refuse to connect at all.

I could imagine a buggy driver even having a problem if you have WPA2 "Mixed Mode" enabled; that is, you have WPA2 AES-CCMP enabled, but you also have TKIP (original WPA) enabled/available. Consider moving to WPA2-only mode. Original WPA was only useful c. 2004, and has just caused problems ever since.

Comment: I checked everything you stated the only thing off was WMM, which every time I turned on, would turn back off on its own. Eventually the router stopped broadcasting on it's own, none of my devices detect it now, so it's safe to say the router died.